# Does Elemental Spellcasting stack with Draconic Power?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

The 'Elemental Spellcasting' feat (Planar Handbook, p39) raises the Caster Level for specific elemental spells (fire, cold, etc). by +1.

The 'Draconic Power' feat (Races of the Dragon, p104) raises the Caster Level by +1, and raises the save DC for the elemental type of your heritage dragon by +1.

Do the caster level increases stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both bonuses are untyped, and neither mentions any special stacking rules, so yes, they stack.  They would also stack with more generic caster level bonuses like the Orange Prism Ioun Stone.  You might also want to look at the Reserve Feats in Complete Mage; each one gives you +1 to your caster level for spells with a particular subschool.